# Section numbering without numbers in book class

Tags: sectioning

I want to add a section without a number, but \section* also excludes it from the numbering, so I try many solution to get this form :

Chapter 1 Name of the chapter
Section 1 : Review of theory
1.1 bla bla 
1.2 so so
Section 2 : Empirical evidence
2.1 .....
2.2 .....

and to get the name of chapter and section in table of content without numbering.
Need help please
here is the code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
% we use \prefix@<level> only if it is defined
\renewcommand{\@seccntformat}[1]{%
  \ifcsname prefix@#1\endcsname
    \csname prefix@#1\endcsname
  \else
    \csname the#1\endcsname\quad
  \fi}
% define \prefix@section
\newcommand\prefix@section{Section \thesection: }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Hello}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsection{Subsection 2}
\section{Go on}
\subsection{Subsection 3}
\end{document}
```

[image: body of text]

Comment: Please show us a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue. Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: If I understand well, you actually want you chapters and sections  be numbered, but the numbers should not appear in the table of contents?

Comment: Or do you want a section that is completely unnumbered, but its entry still appears in the table of contents?

Comment: Thanks for reply. in the text section figure with (section 1.1:) and the subsection with (1.1.1). Witch Iwant is to have section 1 and the subsection with (1.1). the second problem is how that appears in table of contents. My goal is that I have : chapter 1 : Name of the chapter and section 1 : name of the section.

Comment: The code works fine for article class, but not for book.